# Basic question about module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Let $M$ be a $R$-module. Prove that the following are equivalent:
>
> i) $M=0$
>
> ii) For all $R$-module $N$, there only one $R$-homorphism from $M$ to
>   $N$
>
> iii) For all $R$-module $N$, there only one $R$-homorphism from $N$ to
>   $M$

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Have you been able to prove any of the implications?

Answer (score 2):

HINT:  Take $N=M$ and consider the two maps $\operatorname{Id}:M\rightarrow M$ and the $0$ homomorphism.

Comment: Can you explain more precisely?

Comment: @user109584 maybe if you made more precise your problems, it would be easier to provide the appropriate help.